# Why can we assign integers to a char variable

Tags: c

I randomly surfed on StackOverflow. As I saw a question I became clueless. Why can we assign Integer values to a char variable?

**Code snippet**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c = 130;
    unsigned char f = 130;

    printf("c = %d\nf = %d\n",c,f);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
c = -126
f = 130
```

I always thought values have to be assigned to the right type indentifier, why can we do that?

Comment: Because there is nothing like a char constant. There is an implicit cast when assigning an `int` constant to a `char`.

Comment: Try modifying the code to use the `%c` format specifier (instead of `%d`) and see what happens.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya wording nitpick: implicit conversion. A cast is an explicit conversion ;)

Comment: On any computer any data is handled as numbers. Characters usually follow the ASCII-Conversion from numerical values to alphabetical representation.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya what do you mean there is nothing like a char constant? what is exactly a char constant?

Comment: @Alan character constants like `'A'`, `'0'`, `','` are actually of type `int`. They are called character constants because they represent the character set. But their type is `int`.

Comment: So  `A` is a character constant which represents a integer value of the character set, and the compiler 'understands' this constant as Integer and compares this Integer value in the character set and knows than which char to represent? Am I right?

Comment: @Alan sort of, you're making it to complicated. `A` btw is just a letter, could be an identifier. `'A'` is a constant of type `int`. The actual value of that constant is implementation-defined and depends on the character encoding used on the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `char` is an integer type (the smallest one) and values of different integer types can be implicitly converted. But beware that your example code has *implementation defined behavior* on a typical machine with *signed* 8bit `char` *): `130` overflows (the maximum value would be `127`) and the result of overflowing a signed integer type during conversion *is implementation defined*.

You might have asked this question because you thought `char` is for storing characters. This is actuall true, but characters **are** numbers. See [Character Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) for more details.

---

*) whether `char` (without explicit `signed` or `unsigned`) is signed is implementation-defined, as is the number of bits, but there must be at least 8.

Comment: So, If I assign a value (which is in an actual character encoding set I can print is as int `%d`, so I get the number) and when I print it as `%c` I get the corresponding char value of the "encoding set". But when the value is not in there, as in my example 130 it is an undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Alan fixed the answe, the result of a conversion is implementation defined if the correct value can't be represented. Anyways, it's basically as you write. `%c` in `printf()` just outputs the value as a byte, resulting in a character being displayed. `%d` first formats the value as a number (which consists of multiple digits) -- the digits are then output.

Comment: @FelixPalmen signed integer overflow is actually UB. Isn't it?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya yes, but conversion technically isn't the same as overflow (which happens during evaluation of arithmetic expressions). I was on the wrong track myself first ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ah! that makes more sense.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that `char` is unsigned on some implementations. On those implementations, `char` can represent any positive integer up to 2<sup>CHAR_BIT</sup>-1.

Comment: @Alan Bonus reading on Character Encoding: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§6.5.16.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p2)

> In simple assignment (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

This implies that the RHS in an assignment operator is implicitly converted to the type of the variable on the LHS. In your case, the integer constant is converted to `char` type.

Also, there is no `char` constant in C. The character constants like `'a'`, `'B'` are all of `int` type.